# C++ Polymorphism constructor error; Identifier is undefined

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

So I'm trying to implement polymorphism into the beginnings of a battleship program, but I keep getting an intellisense error that tells me one of my identifiers is undefined when I try to call the base class constructor.

Here is the code for the base class, Ship.h:

```
#ifndef SHIP_H
#define SHIP_H
#include <iostream>

class Ship
{
public:
Ship(int, int);
void setX(int);
int getX() const;
void setY(int);
int getY() const;
private:
  int x;
  int y;
};


#endif
```

and here's it's constructor

```
#include "Ship.h"

using namespace std;

Ship::Ship(int userX, int userY)
{
    setX(userX);
    setY(userY);
}
```

The derived class header:

```
#ifndef FRIGATE_H
#define FRIGATE_H

#include "Ship.h"

class Frigate : public Ship {
public:
    Frigate(int);
    void placeShip();
    void setLength(int);
    int getLength() const;
private:
    int length;
};

#endif
```

and it's constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Frigate.h"

using namespace std;

Frigate::Frigate(int specLength) : Ship(userX, userY)
{
    setLength(specLength);
}
```

I keep getting an error when I try to call the ship constructor here that says identifiers `userX` and `userY` are not defined, but I defined them in the constructor for the base class.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: In the `Frigate` initializer, you are passing the undefined variables `userX` and `userY` to the base class constructor, and your compiler is rightly telling you that it doesn't know those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base class constructor takes 2 arguments. Your derived class constructor takes only a single argument. When the constructor of the derived class is called, it will call the base class constructor but you need to give him the 2 values it requires...

I think your constructor of the `Frigate` class should look like

```
Frigate::Frigate(int userX, int userY, int specLength) : Ship(userX, userY), length(specLength)
{
}
```

Comment: Unless he wants to randomize it, in which case you'd have to call the base constructor from inside the body of the `Frigate` constructor after calling random.  I don't know, just guessing what he might want.

Comment: @Donnie in that case he would need to define a default (empty) constructor for Ship because the chain of calls needs to be completed before executing the body of the constructor. As you said we're not totally sure what he wants.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something little that I forgot to do.